# Function body mismatch expected nat got set <int>

Tags: dafny

I am trying to write fibonacci function in Dafny.

```
function fibo(n: nat) : nat 
{
   if n == 0 || n == 1 then {
      n
   }
   else {
      fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
   }
}
```

In VSCode, it is showing Function body type mismatch (expected nat, got set) error.

It looks perfectly fine definition to me. I can't figure out what is wrong with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dafny only allows expressions within functions. Therefore, your if expression curly brackets are actually being treated as a set object. If you remove the curly brackets then your function is well defined.

```
function fibo(n: nat) : nat 
{
   if n == 0 || n == 1 then 
      n
   else 
      fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
}
```